# Did the Priest face a specific direction during the wave offering?

Tags: exodus, law, numbers, leviticus

Exodus 29:24

> 24 And thou shalt put all in the hands of Aaron, and in the hands of his sons;  and shalt wave them for a wave offering before the LORD.

Leviticus 8:29

> 29 And Moses took the breast, and waved it for a wave offering before the LORD:  for of the ram of consecration it was Moses' part;  as the LORD commanded Moses

Numbers 5:25

> 25 Then the priest shall take the jealousy offering out of the woman's hand, and shall wave the offering before the LORD, and offer it upon the altar:

Was there a specific direction that the Priest faced during this ceremony?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Numbers 5:25, though not explicitly stated, the priest first got the wave offering in front of the offeree, waved it facing upward to the Lord, and then turned his back on the offeree to place it upon the altar.

No article I've come across on Google answers the direction/position of the priest specifically.